# Repeat several times particular task in ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

I need to repeat one task several times, i'm trying to use parameters: "retries" and "delay", but it doesn't work:

This is my task, which i need to repeat:

```
- name: Restart service zabbix-agents
  service:
    name: zabbix-agent
    state: restarted
  retries: 3
  delay: 10
```

How can i do it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I fixed indentation, error has gone, but it doesn't work, service doesn't restart 3 times with delay.

Comment: Well, that's a different question though. It doesn't restart three times, because even if you take the common definition of the word "[retry](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/retry)" it is not synonymous with "repeat". Having realised that, you might want to try search SO, for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32557704/2947502) has an answer which you can easily adapt.